# Executorservice and Runnable

Tags: java

I have a list containing data to compute for each pixel (e.g. list size = 1024x768). Now I want to iterate multithreaded through the list and save the computation for each pixel in a HashMap. But whatever I do, I can't manage to make it right. I tried several ways, my last was this one:

```
        ConcurrentMap<T, Color> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<T, Color>();

        ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);

        Iterator<T> it = camera.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Runnable run = () -> {
                int i = 0;
                while (it.hasNext() && i < 1000) {
                    i++;
                    T cameraRay = it.next();
                    if (object.collide(cameraRay.getRay()) == null)
                        map.put(cameraRay, BG_COLOR);
                    else
                        map.put(cameraRay, this.shader.shade(cameraRay.getRay(), object.collide(cameraRay.getRay())).getColor());
                }
            };
            pool.execute(run);
        }
        pool.shutdown();
        try {
            if (pool.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)) {
                System.out.println("Mapsize: " + map.size());
                // Draw Image:
                map.forEach((ray, color) -> {image.setColor(ray, color);});
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Note thet the iterators `hasNext()` Method is synchronized.
The Problem is sometimes a heap problem or simply that the size of the HashMap is less than the list size.

I guess that I didn't understand something correct concering Runnables or the ExecutorService.

I appreciate any help here.

**EDIT:**
I added a `System.out.println(i)` just before the `i++` statement. Despite of checking for `i < 1000` at some point suddenly there appears the following:

```
507
169
86624
625
626
Exception in thread "pool-2-thread-2" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Exception in thread "pool-2-thread-3" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(Unknown Source)
    at raytracer.impl.ParallelRenderer.render(ParallelRenderer.java:78)
    at raytracer.ImageViewer.main(ImageViewer.java:118)
    ... 11 more
Exception in thread "pool-2-thread-4" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at raytracer.impl.TriangleImpl.collide(TriangleImpl.java:87)
    at raytracer.impl.SimpleScene.collide(SimpleScene.java:27)
    at raytracer.impl.ParallelRenderer.lambda$0(ParallelRenderer.java:71)
    at raytracer.impl.ParallelRenderer$$Lambda$48/24559708.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**EDIT 2:**
According to the answer of Warkst, I tried the following

```
Iterator<T> it = camera.iterator();
List<T> buffer = new ArrayList<T>(1000);
while (it.hasNext()) {
    buffer.add(it.next());
    if (buffer.size() >= 1000 || !it.hasNext()) {
        Runnable run = () -> {
            for (T cameraRay : buffer) {
                if (object.collide(cameraRay.getRay()) == null) // No collision
                    map.put(cameraRay, BG_COLOR);
                else
                    map.put(cameraRay, this.shader.shade(cameraRay.getRay(), object.collide(cameraRay.getRay())).getColor());
            }
        };
        pool.execute(run);
        buffer.clear();
    }
}
```

But the very strange is, that the `Runnable` block is never entered now, why?

Comment: Does next() method of iterator is synchronized? Do you consider possibility to use Java 8 streams?

Comment: next() is not synchronized, because this is an exercise which dictates the method signatures. Also it is explicitly claimed to use the ExecutorService...

Comment: What's the type of T? Variable name is `cameraRay`. Is it a big object or a very small one? Does it properly implement `hashCode()` and `equals()`?

Comment: @Magnamag It is very small, composed of two 3d-vectors and two integers for the pixelcoordinates. I guess `hashCode()` and `equals()` work properly because working with the sequential renderer everything works fine.

Comment: @Rafael So two 3d vectors + coordinates... that is up to `8` integers. Each `int` takes `4` bytes, so each T is *at least* `32` bytes. If you have `1024*768=786432` Ts, then, only the keys of your map would take up to `~25 mb`. I'm not saying you should run out of memory because of 25 mb, just trying to understand the numbers. What about `Color`? Is it big or small?

Comment: The `Color` is just a `javafx.scene.paint.Color`

Comment: @Rafael OK, so a color is made up of four `double`s. That takes `25 extra mb`... Also note that for a list of `1024x768` elements, you'd be working with `786,432` Ts, in batches of `1,000` Ts. This means you'd be submitting 787 `Runnable`s to your pool, which has a fixed size of `4`. Most tasks would be waiting in the pool's queue! Size of the map in bytes, added to submitting so many `Runnable`s could be the cause of your `OutOfMemoryError`.

Comment: I think the problem is in `while (it.hasNext()) {
            Runnable run = () -> {
                while (it.hasNext() ...`: you are looping over your collection in an uncontrolled manner using a bunch of separate threads. What if one thread notices it.hasNext is true but then waits with execution while meanwhile some other thread advances the iterator 300 positions? Not to mention meanwhile like 100 runnables might be created in your main thread...

Comment: Maybe someone could point out why the block of the `Runnable` statement is not entered. While debugging, I can see that it jumps right from the `Runnable run = () -> {` to the `pool.execute(run);` line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What confuses me is that your runnables all use the same iterator. What surprises me even more is that you spawn runnables while iterating over the iterator, but that those runnables ALSO manipulate the iterator. This code can (and will, as proven by your question) lead to a bunch of race conditions and the consequent headaches.

I would suggest the following:

1. Get the camera iterator
2. Make an empty buffer
3. Read the first x (e.g. 1000) samples from the iterator into the buffer
4. Create a runnable with the buffer, which will do some work with its 1000 entries
5. Submit the runnable to the service and go back to 2. Repeat until iterator no longer has next.

Assuming your processing of the data is (significantly) slower than iterating once over the camera, this should do the trick. If that's not the case, there's really no reason to be multithreading.

**update 2**

I've updated my code sample to something that works:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, String> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
    Iterator<Integer> it = getIt();
    Task t = new Task(map);
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        t.add(it.next());
        if (t.size()>=1000 || !it.hasNext()) {
            pool.submit(t);
            t = new Task(map);
        }
    }
    pool.shutdown();
    pool.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.DAYS);

    // Breakpoint here to inspect map
    System.out.println("Done!");
}
```

With

```
private static Iterator<Integer> getIt(){
    return new Iterator<Integer>() {

        private int nr = 0;

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return nr < 20000;
        }

        @Override
        public Integer next() {
            return nr++;
        }
    };
}
```

And

```
private static class Task extends ArrayList<Integer> implements Runnable{
    private final ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, String> map;

    public Task(ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, String> map) {
        this.map = map;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try{
            for (Integer i : this) {
                // Simulate some crunching: write to the stdout in 10 iterations for each number: 10 000 prints for each Runnable
                for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                    System.out.println("Iteration "+j+" for "+i);
                }
                // Store something in the map, namely that this Integer, or T in your case, has been processed
                map.put(i, "Done");
            }
        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The breakpoint is hit after about 20-30 seconds and the map contains all Integers paired with the String "Done".

[image: Debug results]

Comment: I made an edit trying to implement your suggestion. Note: I wasn't able to create a generic array of T (`T[] buffer = new T[1000];`)

Comment: Ah, right, you can't create generic arrays. Try using any collection, such as `ArrayList` for a buffer. `ArrayList<T> buffer = new ArrayList<>();`.

Comment: I see in your code snippet that you reuse the buffer for all Runnables. Don't! Create a new ArrayList for each runnable you submit. Otherwise you're effectively sharing one collection among all threads. In fact, most of that code looks weird. I'll cook up an example and update my answer.

Comment: Thanks so far for your effort. Your example also dosn't work. In the end, when all tasks are executed, the `map.size()` is 0. Also your help class needs to be inside a method (named `render(object, camera, image)`) and is also missing a generic type (`Task<T extends CameraRay>`). But considering all this, the end is everytime an empty map and the `awaitTermination()` doesn't end...

Comment: Use the debugger to step through the execution to detect if there are any uncaught exceptions. I couldn't test my code as I don't have the full base code you have and I don't know what T and object are, so I'm sorry if there are any errors. I'll try to make an example that works which you can hopefully adapt. Another tip could be to wrap all the code in the `run()` method inside a try-catch block. Executors and exceptions don't play together so well...

Comment: Thanks so much. With your example I was able to adopt it to my scenario. For small images (e.g. 800x600) the parallel rendering is now twice as fast. But for bigger images (e.g. 1680x1050) the parallel renderer even takes more time as the sequential renderer. I also tried to adopt the maximum task size, because I'm not sure, how big each task should be. But it works. :)
BTW: I had to put the `pool.shutdown()` before the `awaitTermination()` method.

Comment: No problem. Of course shutdown needs to be before await termination, as shutdown queues the shutdown command to be processed when all other submitted jobs are done, and await termination waits for the shutdown job to be executed. Putting them the other way around you are actively creating a deadlock waiting for the service to shut down before you send the shut down command (so your thread deadlocks waiting for something that will never happen). Try to play with the size of the buffer to improve performance. If you have 4 cores, try using a thread pool of size 3.